# how to resolve "Firebug request size limit has been reached by Firebug.." by javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser

I am getting "Firebug request size limit has been reached by Firebug." while posting large data but after searching for this issue got to know it will be resolve by extend browser "extensions.firebug.netDisplayedPostBodyLimit" limit. but I didn't get any solution for this in javascript/jQuery.

Thanks

Comment: this has to done in firefox settings not in jquery

Comment: the net.LogLimit by default is set to 500. If you set it to 0, the limit will be unlimited. You can't do this js to my knowledge, just adjust it in the preferences  https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Firebug_Preferences